# CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM strange effects

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, random

I want to randomly choose a value from a small range of integers (less than 200). As an alternative to

```
SELECT RAND()
```

I'm trying to use

```
CAST(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2) AS INTEGER) AS FLOAT) / 65535
```

but I'm getting some strange effects.

For example:

```
WITH Numbers (num)
     AS
     (
      SELECT num
        FROM (
              VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), 
                     (5), (6), (7), (8), 
                     (9), (10)
             ) AS Numbers (num)
     ), 
     RandomNumber (num)
     AS 
     (
      SELECT CAST(
                  (CAST(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2) AS INTEGER) AS FLOAT) / 65535) 
                     * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Numbers) + 1 
                  AS INTEGER
                 )
     )
SELECT T1.num, R1.num
  FROM Numbers AS T1 
       INNER JOIN RandomNumber AS R1
          ON T1.num = R1.num;
```

I'd expect this to return exactly one row with both column values equal.

However, it returns zero, one or more rows, with the column values being only occasionally equal.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Rename it as Schrödinger's cat or Uncertainty Principle in Sql Server! hahah

Comment: [Blogged about this here](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
select abs(checksum(newid()))%200
```

**Update**

Something fishy is going on here:

```
select 'Not in the range! This is impossible!' [Message]
where cast(CAST(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2) AS int) AS float) / 65535 * 10  as int) 
not in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Hit `F5` until you get the message.

**Update 2**

This query has the same effect:

```
select 'Not in the range! This is impossible!' [Message]
where abs(checksum(newid()))%10
not in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

**Update 3**

```
select N'WTF? Schrödinger''s cat!' [Message], *
from (select 0 union select 1) t(n)
join (select abs(checksum(newid()))%2 rnd) r(n) on t.n = r.n
```

And this last query may sometimes return 2 rows which essentially means that `abs(checksum(newid()))%2` returns 0 and 1 at the same time which is impossible as it is included in "select one row only" statement hence the value gets updated later after the join has been made. :| And then the join occurs again which is flabbergasting.

**Update 4**

It is [a known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=350485&wa=wsignin1.0) at Microsoft Connect. And here's [an insightful article](http://www.codersrevolution.com/index.cfm/2009/10/27/MS-SQL-Server-Table-Variable-And-Nested-Select-Gotcha-Bug) on what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, I'm sure there are more. But can you explain the strange effects of *my* code?

Comment: Maybe the OP has a good reason for needing a crypto-quality random number.

Comment: MS says: "closing this bug as 'won't fix'." Disappointing but I understand their reasoning, even though "optimization [is] allowed to change a program's semantics" does sound quite alarming!